# Can I use two phones as one phone with two screens?

Tags: screen

I have two phones. I would like to have all my files on one, but be able to have two open at once.

Can I set up the second phone such that it extends / adds a second screen to my phone?

I do not want to use BTSync or similar (the second phone has limited storage).

Comment: I don't think it is supported. Maybe third party apps + root.

Comment: @SarpSTA Well yes, I would expect some apps involved. Both phones are rooted.

Comment: To be clear, you want to use another android device as a second monitor for a primary android device? Do you only want screen extension, or also mirroring?

Comment: @jiggunjer I can easily do monitoring with Teamviewer. I'd like to extend the screen, and maybe have  2 apps visible at once (via XPosed window positioning I expect).

Comment: I wouldn't use TeamViewer for simple mirroring. It is more for remote control. So yes,  you want an extended monitor.

Comment: @jiggunjer Well I like to have as few apps as possible and as TV works for that :-). Yeah, extended screens would be nice.

Comment: I've seen a commercial for the IPhone (7?) that looked like you could use multiple screens, side-by-side for stuff like gaming.

Answer (score 0):

Clipboard sharing + cloud drive.
With those two you can do a lot with minimum setup.

For PC like experience you may share your peripherals. [Not trivial](https://blog.ww86.eu/apps/2017/03/05/second-life-of-smartphone.html), though.

The biggest challenge is to sync the clipboard in a safe way. Most solutions are through WiFi router or internet and making a easy Bluetooth connection is a challenge.

Comment: Hi, looks like you're the owner of the linked website. While it's okay to refer to an article written by yourself, take note that *explicit disclosure is required on the post itself*. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).