# Get files of phone with broken everything

Tags: broken-screen, oneplus-one

Dropped my Oneplus One recently, and have bought a replacement already, but would like to get my files off.

The problem:

- screen works, but only top left inch of touchscreen registers
- volume buttons don't work
- USB debugging has disabled itself for some reason (I usually leave it on for this reason)
- when I connect it to the computer using the original USB cable, it just keeps connecting over and over but never shows up (and adb devices doesn't list it)
- I have a USB OTG adapter but it's not registering my mouse or keyboard

Other possibly helpful stuff:

- wifi is connected
- bluetooth is on
- I have an 'ftp server' app on my phone that I could connect to to get the data off if I could open it
- TWRP is installed, phone is unlocked
- lock screen disabled

I've read through the nice broken screen wiki, but nothing on there helps

any creative ideas?

Comment: Did you tried connecting the phone to the computer after rebooting the former in Recovery mode?

Comment: ADB should work as the option is on. Have you ever connected this phone to that computer by ADB before? What do you mean by it keeps connecting over and over ?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I don't know  how to get into recovery mode without my volume buttons

Comment: @esQmo Doesn't ADB need USB debugging to be on?  I have used it with ADB before.  Windows keeps making the 'connected' sound over and over but the device never shows up

Comment: That's what I mean, ADB commands should work as debugging mode is enabled. What is displayed in the device manager? And please check whether the cable is damaged or the USB connector. Check for debris, lint, obstructions .

Comment: @zacaj _"Windows keeps making the connected sound"_, you say? Coupled with OTG not working, it makes me think about a damaged MicroUSB port.

Comment: @esQmo but USB debugging *isn't* enabled, although I don't know why

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman that's my fear as well.  It still charges fine.  I've tried other cables too, and this cable (the original) works fine with the replacement phone

Comment: USB debugging can't disable itself. I'm now sure you have an hardware issue: probably broken USB port.

Comment: Get out a magnifying glass (or a camera with a macro lens) and inspect the USB port—if you're lucky, there might be some obvious, fixable problem. E.g., something got stuck in there when you dropped the phone, or a contact is slightly bent.

Comment: @derobert Nothing obvious

Comment: Any chance the left inch is enough to get a bluetooth mouse paired?

Comment: @derobert I don't have one on hand and every time I've paired via bluetooth it involves clicking ok on the right side of a prompt in the middle of the screen

Comment: Did you tried connecting your phone to pc via usb cable?
since lockscreen is disabled, i think you can get files via MTP mode.

Comment: Look here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/142822/can-i-use-two-phones-as-one-phone-with-two-screens

Comment: Have you got Tasker installed? I am thinking of another way involving using Tasker to get your files move automatically to the ftp shared folder, then access them via your computer. Its a bit awkward but most of the time I use tasker to get me out of tricky situations.

Answer (score 0):

If your ROM and the functionning touch surface of your screen allow it, try to go to settings and activate 0°-90°-180°-270° screen rotation. By turning your phone sideways or upside-down, you might then be able to enable USB debugging again, and proceed to get your files with `adb pull`.

However, since yout OTG adapter doesn't seem to work, it's likely that your USB port is broken too.

Answer (score -1):

So you have TWRP installed. Boot into TWRP, and try to get them via ADB. It should work If device/data is not encrypted. 
Best luck

Comment: How do you propose to boot into TWRP when USB debugging is not working, neither the Volume buttons?